# Magento 2 requesting external REST API

Tags: magento2, module, api, rest-api

I want to call a 3rd party REST API within Magento 2. Is there any class to handle the HTTP requests and responses for that?

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for the suggestions. 
I found that magento is using the Zend HTTP client so i will stick with that at the moment.
An example can be found in the [DHL module](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/app/code/Magento/Dhl/Model/Carrier.php)

**Edit:**

The link above is outdated, but the module can be found [here](https://github.com/netresearch/dhl-module-shipping-m2) and more specifically here: [The Usage of the Zend-Client within Magento](https://github.com/netresearch/dhl-module-shipping-m2/blob/master/Webservice/Client/GlRestClient.php).

Answer (score 2):

If there is no need in Authentication, just use curl (`\Magento\Framework\HTTP\Adapter\Curl`). If OAuth have to be used, take a look at implementation of web API functional tests framework, which relies on 3rd party library, particularly at `\Magento\TestFramework\TestCase\Webapi\Adapter\Rest::call`. You will have to implement something similar in custom module.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend Guzzle.  Its not Magento specific, but should work nicely in Magento 2.

Guzzle is my goto to consume a REST API in PHP.

https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle